# JOIN table with array

Tags: python, mysql, arrays, left-join, sqlobject

I get a response from a JSON API which contains the following data.

```
"data": [
    {
        "num1": 1,
        "num2": 2,
        "txt1": "test3"
    },
    {
        "num1": 4,
        "num2": 5,
        "txt1": "test6"
    }
]
```

Next, I have a database table that looks much the same.

```
|----------------|
|   my_table     |
|----------------|
| num1           |
| num2           |
| txt1           |
|----------------|
```

Now I need to get all the rows in the table that match any of the elements in the data array.

```
SELECT * FROM my_table AS t
LEFT JOIN array AS a
ON t.num1 = a.num1 AND t.num2 = a.num2 AND t.txt1 = a.txt1
```

But of course, I can't treat the array like it's a table. Or can I? How would I solve this?

By the way, I'm writing in Python and I'm using SQLObject library. But this should not make much of a difference.

Comment: `INSERT` json data into database then you can use SQL query.

Comment: I was hoping I could write a query in a clever way. I can't just go insert the json data into the database. Because another process could be doing the same thing at the same time.

Comment: I could iterate over the array. And do a simple `SELECT WHERE` for every element. But that doesn't seem efficient.

Comment: My first idea is to create a TEMPORARY table in the database and insert those values there, before you perform the join... This way other processes would be disturbed by it.

Comment: Or create a `:memory:` SQLite3 table and work on it.

Comment: @576i That sounds like a real solution. But it also feels kindof overkill. What is more efficient? Doing a bunch of `INSERT`s into a temporary table and then a `JOIN`. Or simply doing a bunch of `SELECT WHERE`s?

Comment: @Mtihc I think it all depends on the size of the data you receive by JSON. Remember that you can `INSERT` hundreds of rows into tables with one SQL command. The communication overhead of 2 queries (inserting the data and `SELECT` with `JOIN`) vs. hundreds of `SELECT`s is something to consider. I think, if you expect more than 10 sets of values from the JSON API, the `TEMPORARY TABLE` is the way to go.

Comment: @Maciek Oh yeah, i kindof forgot I can `INSERT` many rows with one SQL command. I understand your point about the size of the data. I think I know enough to make a decision now. Thank you.